# Id column comes from other table JPA entities

Tags: java, jpa, entities

I have two tables in my DB. Table1 with ID and some other columns. Table2 is a relations table where I have the PK from table1 as id in table2 but i dont use a ID in Table2 and it holds some values to other random data.

**In JPA you have to use the @Id annotation. My problem is that I would like to use the entity for table1 to be put in as the @Id for table2 entity. Is this possible and if yes, then how?**

Code so far:
TABLE 1

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Log", schema="logs")
@PersistenceUnit(name="domas")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Log implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false)
    public String id;

    @Column(name="type", nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public LOG_TYPE type;
// and alot more not related code
```

Table 2

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Log_Entity", schema="relations")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "relationType", discriminatorType  = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class LogRelation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="id")
    public Log log;

// and alot more not related code
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a table id of another table? Or are you trying to pick some fields from one table and trying to form a __composite primary key__ for another table? If yes then you should check out the annotations `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId`.

Comment: I'm only trying to get the PK from Table1 into Table2 so that I don't have to declare a Id-annotation on table2 entity since I dont have a real ID column in Table2 only a refId from Table1. But JPA forces me to use Id-annotation so im trying to work around it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mappedBy does not make sense if you do not have @OneToOne inverse side with attribute name id and type LogRelation:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="id")
```

With following it will work:

```
@Id
@JoinColumn(name="lr_id")//or whatever column name you prefer
@OneToOne
Log log;
```

Comment: This class [class com.foo.bar] does not define an IdClass would be produced.

Comment: I would like to know if this type of Id is valid, I have read that the @Id only can used in primitives, wrapers, string, Dates, Arrays, but no other entity. I am not sure, but I guess that if you use other entity, you should override equals and hashCode, please let me know if it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You mean "compound identity", where the identity of one object is (part of) the identity of another object. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/orm/compound_identity.html#1_1_uni